# How to get an error login message in the same page

Tags: jsp, authentication

how can I show the "**Invalid login**" statement for login in the same page `<%

```
String name = request.getParameter("name");
String pass = request.getParameter("password");


Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
Connection c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/login", "", "");
PreparedStatement ps = c.prepareStatement("select * from login1 WHERE NAME=? and PASS=?");
ps.setString(1, name);
ps.setString(2, pass);
ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
if(rs.next())
{
           out.println("valid login");
}

else
    out.println("Invalid login");
```

%>`

Comment: You can't, you'd need to use ajax or something to get the result after the request, also doing code like that inside the page in a scriptlet tag is pretty heavily frowned upon nowadays

Comment: What the statement should I write it in "else" to display the same page with "invalid statement"??